# How to sketch output PDF given the transformation?

Tags: statistics, random

**Question:**
Let Random variable $X$ with $PDF$ = $f_{X}(x)$ be the input to device with input output characteristics as shown below then sketch the $PDF$ of $Y$ i.e, $f_{Y}(y)$

[image]

[image]

**My attempt:**

for  **X>0**

,$Y=X+1\implies  f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}(y-1)$

for **X<0**

,$Y=X-1\implies  f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}(y+1)$

but at

**X=0** there is $2$ units jump from $-1$ to $1$ and derivative of jump discontinuity is impulse so i thought there should be presence of impulse in **PDF** of **Y** but i'm not sure about it .

any help in sketching **O/P PDF Y**  will be greatly appreciated, and it is not a homework problem but from local author textbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the PDF of X can be written as

$$ f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{4} \text{ for } -2 \leq x < 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} \text{ for } 0 \leq x < 1 \\
0 \text{ otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$
but for the edges it remains unclear whether the intervals should or should not include their borders as Dilip pointed out.
Now the function $Y(X)$ applies an offset of $\pm 1$ to any $X$ value corresponding to its sign:
$$Y(X) = \text{sign}(X) + X$$.
Using this, we can write the output PDF as
$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4} \text{ for } -3 \leq x < 1 \\
\frac{1}{2} \text{ for } 1 \leq x < 2 \\
0 \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

If my thoughts are correct, the resulting PDF should look like this:

[image: comparison of PDFs in question]

Answer (score 0):

There is no impulse because there is zero *probability mass* at $0$. As the problem itself shows, it is perfectly all right for a pdf to make sudden jumps in value; note that the graph of $f_X$ (yes, I do mean $X$, not  $Y$) jumps in value at $0$ and the value of $f_X(0)$ cannot be determined from the graph. $f_X(0)$ could have value $\frac 14$ or $\frac 12$ or any value in between (or any nonnegative value for that matter)